# why does the dynamic collection cells in collection view doesnt display as given size and changes after scrolling in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview

I have a collection view.I need to display cells with varying width at sequences. First 4 cells get displayed as required  but after that consecutive 5th image disappears and others are displayed but not in the desired manner. But it doesnot show in the simulator. The view gets distorted when scrolling the collection view.Please anyone help me out in swift 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to resize `UICollectionViewCell` try to implement this method, setting `frame` inside `cellForRowAt` is wrong.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView!, layout _: UICollectionViewLayout!, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath!) -> CGSize {
    if indexPath.row%3 == 0 {
        return CGSize(width: 172, height: 120)
    } else {
        .....
    }//switch, if, whatever
}
```

Comment: func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView!, layout _: UICollectionViewLayout!, sizeForItemAtIndexPath _: IndexPath!) -> CGSize {
        for index in 0...contents.count {
                if (index % 3) == 0 || (index % 3) == 1  {
         yourWidth = 172
            yourHeight = 120
             }
                else  {
                     yourWidth = 355
                     yourHeight = 120
    }
        return CGSize(width: yourWidth, height: yourHeight)
    }      I did in this way but it showed up same sizes for all cells.